# arping Error { bind: Cannot assign requested address } when trying to run it remotely

Tags: sh

Local Server : Lets say local1
Remote Server: Lets say remote1

I have the following shell script in local1 server;

```
#!/bin/sh

comm1=`arping -c 3 -s 192.168.xxx.xx 192.168.yyy.yy | grep "reply from 192.168.yyy.yy" | awk '{print $2,$3,$4}' | tail -1 | awk '{print $3}'`
comm2="192.168.yyy.yy"
       if [[ "$comm1" == *"$comm2"* ]]
       then
       echo "IP is up and running fine"
       else
       echo "IP is not up and running"
       fi
```

If I run the above script in local server, I am getting the desired output, which is "IP is up and running fine".

But if I copy the same script to `remote1` server and try to execute from `remote1` server against `local1` server, it is executing the script but giving the following output;

```
bind: Cannot assign requested address
IP is not up and running
```

So, `remote1` server is able to execute the script on `local1` server, but it is skipping the true condition with error as I mentioned above.

FYI, I ran the following command on remote1 server;

```
ssh root@xxx.xxx.xxx.xx /root/script.sh
```

Any idea where Iam going wrong or how to overcome this error?

Comment: Try assigning to comm1 only the output of `arping -c 3 -s 192.168.xxx.xx 192.168.yyy.yy`. You can print it to debug and then increment the pipe one command at a time.

Comment: Tried that too, not working.

Comment: From the remote 1 server, I simply issued this command to check if it is working basically:
ssh root@<local1 server> arping -c 3 -s 192.168.xxx.xx 192.168.yyy.yy

Still getting same bind error.

Comment: Found it, for the remote server you have to switch IPs `arping -c 3 -s 192.168.yyy.yy 192.168.xxx.xx`. The server IP ends with yyy.yy but you are trying to use xxx.xx as the source IP for the command (-s) which is denied by the remote OS.

Comment: Luis, Thank you so much. It worked.

Comment: Good, added it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

For the remote server you have to switch IPs

`arping -c 3 -s 192.168.yyy.yy 192.168.xxx.xx`

The server IP ends with yyy.yy but you are trying to use xxx.xx as the source IP for the command (-s) which is denied by the remote OS.